# Getting 10 latests post for the 10 latest comments

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a simple yet a mind bending MySQL scenario I am struggling with for the past couple of days.

Here is the table

```
Id | post_id | comment  | extra
1  | 800     | comment_1| foo_text
2  | 801     | comment_1| foo_text
3  | 801     | comment_1| foo_text
4  | 802     | comment_1| foo_text
5  | 802     | comment_1| foo_text
6  | 802     | comment_1| foo_text
7  | 803     | comment_1| foo_text
```

I need to get the 10 latest rows for 10 unique `post_id`s.
ie. The final output should be 10 comments where each comment should belong to a unique post.

This is my attempt.

```
SELECT distinct post_id, id, comment
from comments
order by id desc limit 12)
```

The problem with the above query is, it has duplicate `post_id`. The problem sounds very simple but I cannot seem to understand why it's wrong. Can someone help me?

**PS: I am using MySQL8 and my comments table has more than 5 million records.**

Comment: *I need to get the 10 latest rows for 10 unique post_ids.* Unclear. Do you need 10 latest comments to each of 10 latest post, 100 comments total? *my comments table has more than 5 million records.* Show its CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: @Akina No. I need 10 comments. Each comment should be for a unique post. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
SELECT post_id, id, comment
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM comments
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This does the trick but it's a slow query. It takes about 4 seconds. This will however be my last resort.

Answer (score 2):

First select the post_id and then the comments

> ```
> CREATE TABLE comments (id int,post_id int,comment varchar(50), KEY(id,post_id))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     c.post_id, c.id, c.comment
> FROM
>     comments c JOIn (SELECT DISTINCT
>             post_id, (SELECT MIN(id) FROM comments WHERE post_id= c2.post_id) id
>         FROM
>             comments c2
>         ORDER BY id DESC
>         LIMIT 10) c3 ON c.id = c3.id
> ```
>
> ```
> post_id | id | comment
> ------: | -: | :------
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN SELECT 
>     c.post_id, c.id, c.comment
> FROM
>     comments c JOIn (SELECT DISTINCT
>             post_id, (SELECT MIN(id) FROM comments WHERE post_id= c2.post_id) id
>         FROM
>             comments c2
>         ORDER BY id DESC
>         LIMIT 10) c3 ON c.id = c3.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref              | rows | filtered | Extra                                       
> -: | :----------------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :------------ | :---------- | :------ | :--------------- | ---: | -------: | :-------------------------------------------
>  1 | PRIMARY            | c          | null       | ALL   | id            | null        | null    | null             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                 
>  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | null       | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 9       | db_56794502.c.id |    2 |   100.00 | Using where                                 
>  2 | DERIVED            | c2         | null       | index | id            | id          | 10      | null             |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
>  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | comments   | null       | index | null          | id          | 10      | null             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=805b8fd8e228da349f2023475ed3ceb5)*

Comment: i changed the query and added an index, so that all query can use it